# Perl fork and kill - kill(0, $pid) always returns 1, and can't kill the child

Tags: perl

I am running a perl script on a Linux host.  I'm trying to write a script that forks, where the child starts a program that takes forever and the parent times out after 5 seconds, killing the child.  Here is what I have:

```
my $start = time();
my $timeOut = 5;

my $childPid = fork();
if ($childPid) {
    # I am the parent, and $childPid is my child
    while (kill(0, $childPid)) {
        if (time() > $start + $timeOut) {
            $numKilled = kill(SIGTERM, $childPid);
            printf("numKilled: %s\n", $numKilled);
        }
        sleep 1;
    }
}
else {
    # I am the child - do something that blocks forever
    `adb -s 410bf6c1 logcat`;
    exit;
}
```

Output:

```
aschirma@graphics9-lnx:~$ perl perl-fork-test.pl 
numKilled: 1
numKilled: 1
numKilled: 1
numKilled: 1
numKilled: 1
...
```

The behavior I expect is that I see "numKilled: 1" exactly once, and the child process (and any of its children) is killed after roughly 5 seconds.  But I see from experiment that neither the child nor its children are getting killed.  The `kill(SIGTERM, $childPid)` appears to do nothing.

How can I actually kill the child?

Comment: Are you importing the `SIGTERM` constant from somewhere? I bet it evaluates to 0.

Comment: Are you using `use warnings; use strict;`? Why not?

Comment: Hey guys, so I figured out that the problem I'm seeing is actually a bit different - kill is killing the child process but not any of its children.  I don't want to just edit the whole question, should I start a new one?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but consider checking `if ( defined( $childPid ) )` before doing anything with your child process handle. `fork`returns `undef`if it fails to create the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [perldoc fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html):

> If you fork without ever waiting on your children, you will accumulate
>   zombies. On some systems, you can avoid this by setting $SIG{CHLD} to
>   "IGNORE" .

I was able to get the desired behavior when adding `$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';` to the top of your code.

```
[ben@imac ~]$ perl test.pl
numKilled: 1
[ben@imac ~]$
```

Alternatively, adding `waitpid($childPid, 0);` after `kill` did the trick as well.

Answer (score 6):

Should be something like this. This isn't following best practices, but it should help you with your problem...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX qw(:sys_wait_h);

my $timeOut = 5;
$SIG{ALRM} = \&timeout;
$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE',
alarm($timeOut);

my $childPid = fork();
if ($childPid) {
    while(1) {
        print "[$$]: parent...\n"; 
        sleep(2); 
    }
}else {
    # I am the child - do something that blocks forever
    while(1){
        print "[$$]: child...\n";
        sleep(2);
    }
    exit;
}

sub timeout {
    print "killing $childPid\n";
    print "###\n" . `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep perl` . "###\n";
    if ( ! (waitpid($childPid, WNOHANG)) ) {
        print "killing $childPid...\n";
        kill 9, $childPid;
        die "[$$]: exiting\n";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ forktest.pl
[24118]: parent...
[24119]: child...
[24118]: parent...
[24119]: child...
[24118]: parent...
[24119]: child...
killing 24119
###
cblack   24118 12548  0 14:12 pts/8    00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./forktest.pl
cblack   24119 24118  0 14:12 pts/8    00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./forktest.pl
###
killing 24119...
[24118]: exiting
```

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you are `use`ing neither `strict` nor `POSIX` in your script, so `SIGTERM` is being interpreted as the bareword `"SIGTERM"`, which isn't behaving in a useful way.

`use strict` to make this accidental bareword into an error, then `use POSIX` to pull in the `SIGTERM` constant.

Comment: Or just do `kill 'TERM', $pid` and don't bother with constants.

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html: "You may also use a signal name in quotes."

Comment: I did everything you suggested, but the behavior is the same.  kill(0, $childPid) still constantly shows that the process exists, and I can confirm manually that it does exist.

Answer (score 1):

I am also seeing this behaviour, that kill 0 returns true even after the process was gone; I suspected you might be missing a call to waitpid (often done in a SIGCHLD handler) which would result in this, but even after adding it, the kill 0 continues to return true.

I suggest you use non-blocking waitpid instead of kill (and verify that the process actually does die on a SIGTERM signal - some may not, at least immediately).  You may also want to try SIGINT after a while if SIGTERM didn't work, and in the last resort SIGKILL.

Answer (score 1):

Try killing the process group (use -$pid):

```
kill TERM => -$pid;
```

See perlipc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the '0' you are passing as first argument of 'kill'. When I read the docs, they say that '0' will just check to see whether you can send a signal to the process, without sending it. In your case, you want to send the 'KILL' signal to the child process, so do this:

```
kill( 'KILL', $childPid );
```

Comment: kill(0, $childPid) is basically saying if the process is running then continue..  subsequently he is sending a SIGTERM